# Find out png color type using png++

Tags: c++, png, libpng

I'm using png++, which is working ok, but you need to set the pixel type as a template parameter:

```
 png::image< png::rgb_pixel > image("input.png");
```

The problem is I don't know at compile time whether it is rgb, rgba etc. Can't seem to find a way to get png++ to tell me what info is actually in the png.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try the wrong pixel type in the template parameter?  Do you get an exception, or does the constructed image object have empty/invalid data?

Comment: If you try the wrong pixel type it converts it. and the png::info that is in the png::image gives whatever color type was used as the template parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [reader](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.5/classpng_1_1reader.html).  Then check out the member functions of it's base class, [io_base](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.5/classpng_1_1io__base.html).  I think it has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Hey, author of `png++` here to help :)

If you really need to know what pixel format is in the PNG image, using `png::reader` is the supported way:

```
png::reader< std::istream > reader(my_stream);
reader.read_info();
png::color_type color_type = reader.get_color_type();
```

However, if you don't care of the image color type and just want to load it into, e.g. RGBA buffer, I'd suggest using `png::image< rgba_pixel > image("input.png")`: this will automagically convert PNG image of *any* color type to RGBA for you.

Comment: Actually I'm just handing the image straight over to OpenGL, so it seems a shame to give it an image in RGBA when I could give it one in gray.